# Visual programming tools, why don’t they work with the AST directly?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design, syntax-trees

I've found several open source visual programing tools like Blockly and friends, and other projects hosted at Github, but could't find any that work directly with the abstract syntax tree.

**Why is that?**

I'm asking because once I discovered that every compiler out there has a phase in the compilation process where it parses the source code to an AST, it was obvious to me that some visual programing tools could take advantage of this to give the programer ways to edit the AST directly in a visual way, and also to do the round trip from source to node-graph and then back again to source when needed.

For instance one could think that from the [JavaScript AST Visualizer](http://jointjs.com/demos/javascript-ast) to an actual JavaSript visual programming tool there isn’t too much of a difference.

**So, what am I missing?**

Comment: ASTs are very verbose, and not very convenient for programming. They were designed for compilers, not programmers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_editor

Comment: What do you mean by "work directly with the abstract syntax tree"? Arguably all of the block-based tools like Blockly are editing the AST: they represent edges by nesting (or stacking, if you prefer to see it that way), and the user can edit the tree by (say) drag and drop.

Comment: It's a great question a lot of us who like compilers have had. I think the short answer is that if you could do this and make it user-friendly, people *would* use it. The only problem is, that's a big "if".

Comment: "every compiler out there [produces] AST" -- I don't think that is true. While a convenient intermediate step for some purposes, it's not necessary.

Comment: Have you tried [Human Resource Machine](http://store.steampowered.com/app/375820/)?  It sounds similar to what you're asking about, but for assembly-language, and in game-form.

Comment: Have you looked into [Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html)?  *"[It's] not so much that Lisp has a strange syntax as that Lisp has no syntax. You write programs in the parse trees that get generated within the compiler when other languages are parsed. But these parse trees are fully accessible to your programs. You can write programs that manipulate them."*

Comment: @Wildcard Thanks for pointing out about Lisp, haven’t tried yet though.

Comment: @Wildcard: Was about to point out lisp myself

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Many of these tools **do** work directly with the abstract syntax tree (or rather, a direct one-to-one visualisation of it). That includes Blockly, which you've seen, and the other block-based languages and editors like it ([Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), [Pencil Code](https://pencilcode.net/)/[Droplet](https://github.com/droplet-editor/droplet), [Snap!](http://snap.berkeley.edu/), [GP](http://dspace.mit.edu/openaccess-disseminate/1721.1/98451), [Tiled Grace](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~mwh/minigrace/tiled/#sample=orbital), and so on).

Those systems don't show a traditional vertex-and-edge graph representation, for reasons explained elsewhere (space, and also interaction difficulty), but they are directly representing a tree. One node, or block, is a child of another if it is directly, physically inside the parent.

---

I built one of these systems ([Tiled Grace](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~mwh/minigrace/tiled/#sample=orbital), [paper](https://michael.homer.nz/Publications/VISSOFT2014/paper.pdf), [paper](https://michael.homer.nz/Publications/VISSOFT2013/paper.pdf)). I can assure you, it is very much working with the AST directly: what you see on the screen is an exact representation of the syntax tree, as nested DOM elements (so, a tree!).

[image: Screenshot of nested Tiled Grace code]

This is the AST of some code. The root is a method call node "for ... do". That node has some children, starting with "_ .. _", which itself has two children, a "1" node and a "10" node. What comes up on screen is exactly what the compiler backend spits out in the middle of the process - that's fundamentally how the system works.

If you like, you can think of it as a standard tree layout with the edges pointing out of the screen towards you (and occluded by the block in front of them), but nesting is as valid a way of showing a tree as a vertex diagram.

It will also "do the round trip from source to node-graph and then back again to source when needed". In fact, you can see that happen when you click "Code View" at the bottom. If you modify the text, it'll be re-parsed and the resulting tree rendered for you to edit again, and if you modify the blocks, the same thing happens with the source.

---

Pencil Code does essentially the same thing with, at this point, [a better interface](https://pencilcode.net/edit/intro). The blocks it uses are a graphical view of the CoffeeScript AST. So do the other block- or tile-based systems, by and large, although some of them don't make the nesting aspect quite as clear in the visual representation, and many don't have an actual textual language behind them so the "syntax tree" can be a bit illusive, but the principle is there.

---

What you're missing, then, is that these systems really *are* working directly with the abstract syntax tree. What you see and manipulate is a space-efficient rendering of a tree, in many cases literally the AST a compiler or parser produces.

Answer (score 6):

At least two reasons:

1. Because source code is a *much* more concise representation.  Laying out an AST as a graph would take up a lot more visual real estate.

   Programmers prize having as much context as possible -- i.e., having as much code present all at once on the screen at the same time.  Context helps them better manage complexity.  (That's one reason why many programmers use these crazy small fonts and enormous 30" screens.)

   If we tried to display the AST as a graph or tree, then the amount of code that you could fit on a single screen would be much less than when it is represented as source code.  That's a huge loss for developer productivity.
2. AST's are intended for compiler programming, not for easy understanding by programmers.  If you took an existing AST representation and displayed it visually, it probably would be harder for developers to understand, because ASTs weren't designed to be easy for developers to learn.

   In contrast, source code usually *is* designed to be readable/understandable by developers; that is normally a critical design criteria for source code, but not for ASTs.  ASTs only need to be understood by the compiler writers, not by everyday developers.

   And, in any case, the AST language would be a second language developers have to learn, in addition to the source language.  Not a win.

See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/119463/34181 for some additional potential reasons.

Comment: "In contrast, source code is designed to be readable/understandable by developers" - counterexample: most esolangs, Perl, Lisp

Comment: "Because source code is a much more concise representation."; "the AST language would be a second language developers have to learn, in addition to the source language" -- these are arguments against *all* visual PLs but does not help to explain the distinction the OP is concerned about.

Comment: "(That's one reason why many programmers use these crazy small fonts and enormous 30" screens.)" -- if you need a big-ass screen to view enough context, maybe you're spaghetti-coding? ;)

Comment: @Raphael Perhaps, but it's less effort to throw money at it than refactoring!

Comment: @JanDvorak, OK, I got you.  Good one.  (I've edited the answer with appropriate hedge words.)

Comment: @JanDvorak, ...LISP is a counterexample because the AST *is* the language -- which is what gives it its expressive power; writing LISP code that recompiles your other LISP code is as easy as writing code that modifies standard LISP data structures... which *are exactly what LISP code is written in*. There's a reason it's lasted over half a century -- the family's design is uncommonly expressive. Go had to have its async extensions plumbed deep into the language and runtime; for Clojure, it's just a library. See also: [Beating the Averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html).

Answer (score 3):

The typical AST by compilers is rather complex and verbose.  The directed graph representation would quickly become quite hard to follow.  But there are two large areas of CS where ASTs are used.

1. Lisp languages are actually written as AST. The program source code is written as lists and directly used by the compiler and/or interpreter (depending upon which variant is being used).
2. Modelling languages, e.g. UML, and many visual domain specific languages use graphical notations which are effectives abstract syntax graphs (ASG) at a higher level of abstraction than the typical general purpose language AST.